# Missing PostgreSQL libraries while compiling inside Cygwin

Tags: windows, postgresql, cygwin, shared-libraries

I'm trying to compile osm2pgsql inside Cygwin on a Windows7 machine.

While running configure script I'm getting following error message:

```
checking for PostgreSQL libraries... ./configure: line 17889: /cygdrive/c/Program: No such file or directory
./configure: line 17890: /cygdrive/c/Program: No such file or directory
./configure: line 17891: /cygdrive/c/Program: No such file or directory
./configure: line 17894: /cygdrive/c/Program: No such file or directory
./configure: line 17900: /cygdrive/c/Program: No such file or directory
configure: error: postgresql client library not found
```

Solution should be adding library folder location to PATH system variable, or have copy of libraries in location of PostgreSQL executables.

Location of PostgreSQL executables is

> C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin

and libraries location is

> c:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.1\lib

both of them are included in PATH system variable (Windows7), but libraries are claimed missing anyway.

Copying libraries into ...\bin directory did not help either.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Out of interest ... why Cygwin?

Comment: Compiled binaries for windows i have found have [problems on 64 systems](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql#Windows) & on [osm2pgsql github site](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql) compiling on Windows machines is not mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Run `./configure --help` to see is there is a parameter like `--with-<PostgreSQL>=/path/to/PostgreSQL` where you can include the files you already have in `C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.1`. If so run `./configure --with-<PostgreSQL>=/path/to/PostgreSQL`.

Comment: In Cygwin desired path would be `/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin`. Running `/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin` ends with `-bash: PostgreSQL: No such file or directory` error. From shell i can cd or ls theese directories.

Comment: Go where there is the configure of osm2pgsql, then type `./configure --help`, look for an option to include the files you have of PostgreSQL (bin, include, lib, etc.). It should look like --with-PostgreSQL=ARG. When you find it, use 1) `./configure --with-<option you found>=/your/path/to/PostgreSQL` 2 ) `make` 3) `make install`

Comment: As I tried to say... when running `./configure --with-<option I have found>=/my/path/to/PostgreSQL` i get `-bash: PostgreSQL: No such file or directory` error. @Thronghar

Comment: @Empty_Mind You cannot link to win32 `libpq` from a Cygwin binary. They're effectively different platforms. You need a Cygwin `libpq` (PostgreSQL client library) if you're going to compile for Cygwin. Alternately, you may wish to consider compiling with mingw32, which produces native Windows binaries and can use native Windows libraries - but then you can't use Cygwin to install dependencies because they're Cygwin libraries. (Also, many `configure` scripts do not handle spaces in paths correctly; I suspect that's the immediate issue here. Use the DOS shortname like `PROGRA~1`).